# Por que utilizamos números romanos?

Tags: números

Em alguns casos no português (também no espanhol e italiano, mas não no inglês ou alemão) escrevemos números romanos ao invés do sistema arábico, por exemplo ao descrever séculos:

> O século XXI já começa mais documentado do que qualquer um dos anteriores [(fonte)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=61KbsV-TjloC&lpg=PR6&ots=IlDNoKaYJD&dq=S%C3%A9culo%20XXI&lr&pg=PR6#v=onepage&q=S%C3%A9culo%20XXI&f=false)

De fato é mais fácil ler algarismos arábicos, pois os utilizamos para todo o restante dos casos. Se é assim, por que ainda utilizamos algarismos romanos?

Comment: No alemão de fato é mais raro (fora mostradores de relógios), mas os algarismos romanos são comuns em inglês (vide, e.g., a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Modern_use)). Sobre as razões de ainda ser usado, são históricas e estilísticas (nada impediria de "Rambo II" ser escrito "Rambo 2", e maioria dos relógios modernos usa algarismos arábicos).

Comment: @stafusa Tem razão! Interessantemente para séculos o inglês usa o arábico, e.g. "14th century"

Comment: Copyright MMXXII e comun em inglês

Answer (score -1):

Em primeiro lugar, por uma questão de tradição, e segundo por uma razão de propriedade numérica: nosso sistema de contar os séculos é uma herança dos romanos, e assim continuou quando o zero ainda não havia sido introduzido. Na ausência de um século zero, ao sistema árabe não era considerado numerar os séculos com a devida propriedade.

Comment: Usa-se algarismos romanos independente de haver norma ABNT para o texto em questão ou não. Não há norma ABNT para livros de romance, no entanto, pode-se encontrar algarismos romanos lá.

Comment: Percebo. Entretanto, vossa resposta ainda não responde a pergunta. A pergunta é sobre o uso dos algarismos romanos de forma geral, e não sobre o uso dos algarismos romanos em textos jurídicos. Contudo, se souberes por que houve a necessidade de tornar os algarismos romanos obrigatórios nesses tipos de texto, acho que ajuda a elucidar mais a questão.

Comment: Ninguém disse que são obrigatórios, porque não são. Como foi comentado, é uma questão de tradição e costume, não de gramática. Você pode optar por grafar século 21, século vinte e um, ou século XXI, dá na mesma.